# How to mark outbound FTP traffic with iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, bandwidth

i have a user called "testuser" in my debian system and i want to mark the FTP traffic going from testuser's account

how can i do that?

i use following commands to mark all the outgoing traffic for "testuser"

```
iptables -t mangle -N HTB_OUT
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -j HTB_OUT
iptables -t mangle -A HTB_OUT -m owner --uid-owner testuser -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

how to set two marks for "testuser"? one for FTP traffic only and one for all other traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a --dport (--destination-port) option. You'll need at least two of them - 20:21 for FTP traffic and !20:21 for non-FTP.

Comment: can you please show me how to combine it with "-m owner --uid-owner testuser -j MARK --set-mark" ?

Comment: You simply add it as an option to the command line.

Comment: it gives me error "invalid argument" when its added to this "iptables -t mangle -A HTB_OUT -m owner --uid-owner testuser -j MARK --set-mark 10"

Comment: Try "man iptables"

Comment: thanks by adding "-p tcp --dport 20:21" command executed without errors but not for "-p tcp --dport !20:21" it gives "-bash: !20: event not found"

Comment: after few experiments it works with space between ! and 20 "p tcp --dport ! 20:21"